# Tensorflow: How to change optimizer after restoring a model?

Tags: python, optimization, tensorflow

I am quite new to TensorFlow and fail to know how to tackle this simple problem regarding changing optimizer.

For example, I'd like to change 'AdamOptimizer' to 'MomentumOptimizer' after restoring a model.

```
# optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.learning_rate)
optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate=self.learning_rate, momentum=0.8)
```

If "self.saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())" is put after the optimizer, a NotFoundError  is raised like this.

**NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key dynamic_seq2seq/decoder/attention/attention_layer/kernel/Momentum not found in checkpoint**

And if "self.saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())" is put before the optimizer, after model is loaded and starts to train, a FailedPreconditionError  is raised like this.

**FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value dynamic_seq2seq/decoder/memory_layer/kernel/Momentum**

And "saver.restore(session, model_file)" is called after these codes.

In TensorFlow, how to change optimizer after restoring a model successfully without the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

new_optimizer = tf.train.XXXOptimizer()

var_list = tf.trainable_variables()
# or if some variables are frozen
var_list = tf.tf.global_variables()

# Tell the new optimizer
new_optimizer._create_slots(var_list=var_list)
```

A little bit background information:

Optimizers can define extra variables that they need. They create those variables for *each* trainable variable. This becomes problematic in two cases

1. One changes the optimizer during the training, as it is the scope of this question.
2. One unfreezes a variable during training. By implication, this variable was flagged as `trainable=False` before. This means that the previously used optimizer (can be the same or a different one) did not create these auxiliary variables. They are not included in the checkpoint then. Loading fails, because they are assumed to be present. The above example can become much simpler then:

```py
trainable = False  # or True
layer = tf.layers.Layer(trainable=trainable)
outputs = layer(inputs)
new_optimizer._create_slots(var_list=layer.variables)
```

The above works for all optimizers, because by convention, every `tf.train.XXXOptimizer` has to implement `_create_slots()` if additional variables shall be created. It is not the best solution ever, however, because it uses a private API.